# Black 1976 caplet value

Tags: interest-rates, derivatives, black76

I've seen from two sources different formulas for the caplet value (Black 1976):

- $$Caplet_1 = N\cdot DiscountFactor_{0,k}\cdot yrFrcn_{k,k+1}\cdot [F_{k,k+1}\cdot N(d_1) - R_k\cdot N(d_2)]$$
- $$ Caplet_2 = N\cdot \frac{DiscountFactor_{0,k}\cdot
     yrFrcn_{k,k+1}}{1+F_{k,k+1}\cdot yrFrcn_{k,k+1}}\cdot
     [F_{k,k+1}\cdot N(d_1) - R_k\cdot N(d_2)]$$

With $F_{k,k+1}$ as the forward rate, $R_k$ as the strike and $yrFrcn_{k,k+1}$ as year fraction between date $k$ and $k+1$

I'd like to know which one is correct.

The sources:

- Caplet 1: https://www.slideshare.net/uichong/chap-26 slide 6.
- Caplet 2: http://slideplayer.com/slide/3558788/ slide 3.

Comment: @noob2 DiscountFactor = $e^{-rT}$ in $Caplet_2$ source, while it's equal to $P(0,t_{k+1})$ in $Caplet_1$ source.

Comment: @What is the $T$ above? Is it the $t_k$?

Comment: @Gordon in DiscountFactor = $e^{-rT}$ you mean? I undertand it as $t_{k+1}$, but I'm not sure, it could be $t_k$. But the main difference is in the denominator $1+F_{k,k+1}\cdot yrFrcn_{k,k+1}$ of the $Caplet_2$ formula.

Answer (score 2):

Note that
\begin{align*}
F_{k, k+1} = \frac{1}{yrFrcn_{k,k+1}}\left(\frac{P(0, t_k)}{P(0, t_{k+1})}-1 \right).
\end{align*}
Then, in $Caplet_2$,
\begin{align*}
\frac{DiscountFactor_{0,k}\cdot yrFrcn_{k,k+1}}{1+F_{k,k+1}\cdot yrFrcn_{k,k+1}}&=\frac{P(0, t_k)\cdot yrFrcn_{k,k+1}}{1+F_{k,k+1}\cdot yrFrcn_{k,k+1}} \\
&=P(0, t_{k+1})\cdot yrFrcn_{k,k+1},
\end{align*}
which is consistent with $Caplet_1$.

Comment: Hi, Gordon. Would you like to have a look at my question https://quant.stackexchange.com/q/38719/6686? Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Hans. I do not know that, but I will have a look.